# Resizing window to maximum size

Tags: awesome-wm

is there a way to resize the current window to maximal size in Awesome wm? Something like maximizing, but without locking the maximum-ness. Currently, when I want to maximize a floating window I cycle through the layouts, the non-floating layouts resize the window to the desired size and then I return back to the floating layout.

How to do it better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a clientkey with a function like `function(c) c:geometry(c.screen.geometry) end`.

Answer (score 0):

In Awesome 4.0+ (currently the Git master version), there is:

[awful.placement.maximize](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/libraries/awful.placement.html#maximize)